# Why is the move-constructor not called?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is nothing being printed in this example? I'm compiling in Clang on Coliru.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    S()    noexcept = default;
    S(S&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move-ctor"; }
};

void f(S) {}

int main()
{
    f(S{});
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11 move constructor not called, default constructor preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099603/c11-move-constructor-not-called-default-constructor-preferred)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler is performing *copy elision*, which is allowed per paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard even if your move constructor, copy constructor, or destructor have side effects:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects.

The term *copy elision* is used even when a move is being elided:

> This elision of copy/move operations, **called *copy elision***, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> [...]
>
> — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
>
> [...]

With GCC, you can use the `-fno-elide-constructors` to inhibit copy elision. In this case, you would see that the move constructor gets invoked, as in this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b7c7a72b9fc7bb1f12d03b9595111f85-9e84fdc2d22f4cab4cc066ed54711a46).

Comment: Why is it called copy elision if I am moving?

Comment: @user2030677: That's Standardese terminology. Mostly for historical reasons (in C++03 only copies could be elided, since move semantics did not exist)

Comment: @user2030677 you are eliding a *copy*, which could have been performed with the copy constructor, or the copy move constructor.

Comment: Another question: How do I stop RVO/NRVO from happening? Is there a linker option for that?

Comment: @user2030677: RVO/NRVO is actually copy elision, so on GCC that's the flag I wrote about at the end of my answer (btw, copy elision is a compiler's job, not a linker's job). On Clang, the flag is the same, but that option has a bug in Clang, so I'd suggest not to use it. On MSVC I am not sure (perhaps try disabling all optimizations in Debug build)

Comment: But I did include that flag and its not working -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e86f35489281a37bf1e0557bf350db42-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f

Comment: @user2030677: Sorry, I forgot an `s` (edited the answer): it is `-fno-elide-constructors`. But again, Clang has a bug with that, so I suggest using GCC for testing it

Comment: Where can I find a GCC compiler to do that? Liveworkspace is down and (AFAIK) ideone doesn't allow me to use the command line.

Comment: @user2030677: Coliru does (see the live example I linked in my question). Just use `g++-4.8` instead of `clang++`

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. Thanks. Where can I find info on more stuff like that?

Comment: @user2030677: What do you mean by "stuff like that"? :D Coliru? I don't know, I've just seen people used it this way and did the same

Comment: I meant like a list of compiler options like the one you showed me.

Comment: @user2030677: That depends on the compiler. You should check the compiler's documentation