# Pushing std::thread by value into a list

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

My code looks like the following:

```
#include <list>
#include <thread>

void my_function(int val) {
    // Empty function
}

int main() {
    std::list<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(my_function, i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The fact that I use `threads.push_back()` means that I run the copy-constructor `std::thread::thread(const thread&)`.

- Is it safe?
- Should I use `std::move` ?

Please suppose that I don't know in advance how many threads I am going to need, so replacing the list by an array or by an `std::vector`, is not an option for me (`std::vector` would be an option only if I knew the number of threads in advance, as I cannot afford the vector's `realloc` operations).

Comment: "_The fact that I use `threads.push_back()` means that I run the copy-constructor `std::thread::thread(const thread&)`._" Such constructor is [`delete`d](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), so it's impossible for you to run it.

Comment: Why not use `emplace_back`? It sounds like what you're after. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back

Comment: "Should I use std::move" no, temporary is already an rvalue, you need to use `std::move` to cast named variable.

Comment: So `emplace_back` will function as the constructor of the list template, and will thus make sure that the object is constructed directly on the list?

Comment: @Slava you're saying that even if the copy constructor was not "deleted", it would not be called anyway, as the "temporary" thread is an rvalue?

Comment: Yep, with `emplace_back` the object gets constructed at the location provided by the list. Just as if you had called placement new at that address.

Comment: @SomethingSomething `std::thread(my_function, i)` is an rvalue. `std::vector::push_back` has an overload for rvalues which uses move semantics and makes no copies.

Comment: "it would not be called anyway", not quite that. It would prefer move ctor or assignment operator if such one exists.

Comment: I am learning here new things today. Just to be sure - the fact that the thread constructor is not assigned to any variable, defines it as an rvalue? Which means it is going to be accepted by a method that gets `std::thread&&` and be constructed only when that function is called?

Comment: "the fact that the thread constructor is not assigned to any variable" you should use proper terminology. You do not assign constructor to something, you create an instance of `std::thread` class, what type that instance has depends on expression.

Comment: @SomethingSomething - Almost. It's constructed at the call site so that the reference could bind to it. Then, inside the list node, another thread is constructed by *moving* the contents of the one at the call site. The move is safe. There is only ever a single handle that owns the thread. And I must second Slava, you should get a refresher book on C++11 to catch up on terminology.

Comment: @StoryTeller or that move could be eliminated by optimizer and it would be constructed in place. But it does not matter in this case - result will be the same.

Comment: @Slava - Only if the move constructor has no observable behavior and the push back is inlined. Otherwise the core language itself requires two instances.

Comment: @StoryTeller `push_back()` is a template, so it can be inlined easily. For side effect, I think compiler allowed to omit copy ctor even if there are side effects. It is not the same for move ctor?

Comment: @Slava - `push_back` is a black box. Depending on the machinery it invokes it can either be inlined easily or not. Ans since I cannot predict it reliably I would not wish to lead someone astray by pretending I can. And if you think about guaranteed copy elision, it doesn't hold when passing by function arguments by reference. The reference must bind to something. It's not even entirely reliable when passing by value.

Comment: " if you think about guaranteed copy elision" no I do not, even before guaranteed copy elision compiler was allowed to omit copy ctor even if it has side effects. And I am not saying if it will elimininate for sure or not, I just said it is possible that move ctor would be eliminated here.

Comment: Does the fact that my threads are "moved" to the list, which means they are going to be copied to the heap, means that I will need to manually iterate on the list and delete each of them?

Comment: @Slava - "Side-effects" is not what I meant by observable behavior. I mean what the C++ standard means, and it doesn't allow eliminating it, period.

Comment: @SomethingSomething - No.

Comment: @StoryTeller looks like you are wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099603/c11-move-constructor-not-called-default-constructor-preferred

Comment: @Slava - Looks like you just didn't read any of the answers. Nothing there applies to the case of forwarding function arguments.

Comment: If the two constructors are implemented - both copy constructor and move constructor (unlike in std::thread, where the copy constructor is deleted), which one will be called if the passed item is "temporary", like in the example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The fact that I use threads.push_back() means that I run the copy-constructor

No, it does not. Since C++11 `push_back` is overloaded to accept an rvalue reference to the list's value type.

You cannot run `std::thread`'s copy constructor, since it's declared as deleted. The above mentioned overload of `push_back` was added for this exact purpose of supporting move only types, like a thread handle.

If you want to initialize the thread directly into the container without a move, then `emplace_back` can do that. But you need to pass the parameters for the `std::thread` constructor in, not a thread that is initialized from them:

```
threads.emplace_back(my_function, i);
```

Comment: Does it mean that the code is safe? Just as if I assigned the thread directly to the placeholder in the list?

Comment: @SomethingSomething - Yes, as far as the thread creation itself goes it's safe. The standard library deletes the copy constructor so that unsafe creation won't even compile. And the move constructor does the sane thing. It aims to be correct by construction.